# Error: Deployment Failed while using Matic Test Network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I am getting started with Application development on Matic. And I am following the instruction as provided on the docs  https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/getting-started

But I faced problem while using truffle. After I run the command

```
truffle migrate --network matic
```

The error as follow:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'matic'
> Network id:      80001
> Block gas limit: 20000000 (0x1312d00)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- insufficient funds for gas * price + value.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.1.55 (core: 5.1.55)
Node v10.19.0
```

The configuration file of truffle as follow:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    matic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today`),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
    }
  }
}
```

It worked fine for the develop network using

```
truffle develop
```

Can someone tell me how to overcome error while using Matic Test Network?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have enough MATIC for the transaction, you can get some from [here](https://faucet.matic.network/) and transfer them to the account[0]. I had issues deploying with truffle as all my tokens were at account[1] rather than account[0]

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was ETH, ensuring i had tokens in the first account did the trick

[image]